# variable name for require'ing a module and jslint

Tags: node.js, jslint

I've just started to play around with nodejs and came across jslint, so I decided to test my code using this: [jslint module for nodejs](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint). I have 2 questions:

1.- Take for example this snippet:

```
var util = require('util');
```

when running jslint like:

```
jslint --indent 4 --white --regexp --goodparts file.js
```

it will produce:

```
/*jslint indent: 4, white: true, regexp: true, goodparts: true, node: true, es5: true, onevar: true, undef: true, nomen: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, newcap: true */
  1 1,5: Redefinition of 'util'.
    var util = require('util');
  2 1,10: Read only.
    var util = require('util');
```

If I change the snippet to:

```
var utilButADifferentName = require('util');
```

The output is completely clean.

The code *seems* to work ok either way. So who can enlighten me about this? :)

2.- Take the following snippet:

```
function Some() {
}

exports.Some = Some;
```

Running jslint with the same options yields:

```
  1 4,1: 'exports' has not been fully defined yet.
    exports.Some = Some;
```

Is this because of the options I'm using with JSLint or am I missing something else? Any good tips on the best (generically speaking) options to use with JSLint when "linting" a nodejs code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It looks like node-jslint comes with a slightly out of date version of node.js. The issue was with *util* appears [to have been fixed](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/42).

You might want to take a look at JSHint and node-jshint. I believe these are known to be much more configurable than JSLint.

2) Is it not simply because you have not initialised *exports* before you used it?

```
function Some() {
}

var exports = {
    Some: Some
};
```

Comment: excellent, did not notice that was an open/closed issue. tx :)

Answer (score 3):

jsLint is built for client-side JavaScript only. In my experience, making it play nice with server-side code, isn't worth the trouble - at least compared to the relatively low overhead of switching to something like [jshint](http://jshint.org).

Wrt. your errors, `util` is a reserved variable name in the eyes of jslint (why it complains about you overwriting it), and as `exports` is a purely server-side thing, jslint barfs over that as well (it believes your'e writing to `undefined`).

By comparison, jshint has a Node.js-mode, where all the global Node.js stuff is pre-defined and passes without incident (*if* you write otherwise linting code).

Answer (score 1):

JSLint seems to be out of date on node's native objects. Just remove the `node:true` option and ignore warnings, or create your own (updated) definition of globals:

```
/*global Buffer: false, clearInterval: false, clearTimeout: false, console: false, global: false, module: false, exports: false, process: false, require: false, setInterval: false, setTimeout: false, __filename: false, __dirname: false */
```

See the defaults being used: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html